# Which part is wrong in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

He *insisted* that she *met* with her lawyer before *signing* the *final* papers.

I found this in a test book, one of the words in italic is grammatically incorrect, which one is it?

Comment: The sentence looks correct to me. Is there a header for the question that gives more information?

Comment: *Meet* could make the sentence different, but both the original and this would be correct.

Comment: I'm not fully sure, but  "*she **(should) meet** with*" would be a possible option.(?)

Answer (score 2):

"He *insisted* that she *met* with her lawyer before *signing* the *final* papers."

This sentence has no grammatical mistake in it. It is correct and makes sense; I gather that 'he' is insisting to some third party that a woman had met with her lawyer before signing some papers that were the final part of some transaction. I suppose he could have been insisting this to the woman if she had forgotten; that's a little strange, but the sentence would still be correct.

If he was insisting to this woman that she needed to do this and she had not, as opposed to insisting to a third party that she had done it, then the verb should be "meet"; he could have, in this case, been advising her that the meeting with her lawyer was necessary before signing these papers.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a simple change that would make any of 'insisting', 'signing', or 'final' an incorrect word.